# vue component does not update when data is changed external

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

My component does not update the loaded property when Store.loaded changes:

Component

```
import { Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import Component from 'nuxt-class-component'
import { Store } from '../repositories'

@Component
export default class Layout extends Vue {
    loaded = Store.loaded
}
```

Store

```
class Root {
    loaded = false
}

export let Store = new Root()
export default Store
```

Comment: Could you include where and why are you changing it externally?

Comment: e.g. store includes a user property and a games array. A user can join game --> the user has a method that sets a participating property in the game object to true. But this change is not picked up. (I have to mention that not all properties of store are already present when the component loads. --> i.e. the games are dynamically loaded)

Answer (score 2):

In your example `Store` is just plain function (class), without any reactivity (no Vue watchers attached for `Store.loaded` field).

Only properties inside component's `data` are reactive. If you want reactive single store outside of vue components (better for big frontend applications), you should use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)

Simple example will be:

**App.vue:**

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import store from './store';
import ChildComponent from './components/ChildComponent.vue';

export default {
  store,
  components: { ChildComponent },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['toggleLoaded']),
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      isLoaded: 'isLoaded',
    }),
  }
}

</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <a href="javascript:" @click="toggleLoaded">Toggle loaded</a>

    <h3>Root component: </h3>
    <div>The loaded flag is: {{ isLoaded }}</div>

    <ChildComponent />
  </div>
</template>
```

**components/ChildComponent.vue:**

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      isLoaded: 'isLoaded', //accessing to same data, as root through single Vuex state
    }),
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h3>Child component</h3>
    <div>The loaded flag is: {{ isLoaded }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And reactive Vuex store:

**store/index.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  loaded: false
};

const getters = {
  isLoaded: state => state.loaded,
};

const mutations = {
  toggleLoaded: (state) => {
    state.loaded = !state.loaded;
  }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  mutations,
  // actions,
  getters,
  strict: true
});
```

You can find full source of this example [on GitHub](https://github.com/alexkalinin-stackoverflow-examples/q47365787-reactivity).

Comment: I am actually currently using vuex and want to refactor away from it. The hassle with dispatch/commit and the resulting breakage of intellisense outweigh the benefits for my use case.

Comment: `>intellisense` - if you mean code completion, you can extract actions/commits names to constants. For example, see [mutation-types.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/examples/shopping-cart/store/mutation-types.js)-file in [shopping-cart-vuex-example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart)

Comment: `>hassle with dispatch/commit` I have no experience with [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/)-library, but I heard, it is simpler then [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) and vuex. Perhaps you can use it as other  single store analogue. Also I just found this project: [vue-mobx](https://github.com/dwqs/vue-mobx) - might be useful for you.