# Vue component .$on use case

Tags: vuejs2

Its not clear to me how to use the [.$on(...)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) method available in every Vue instance. I am sure I am probably missing some use case where an event would be emitted and consumed by the same Vue component (?) but currently I am not able to imagine many. Also, where would this wiring be performed. Would that be in a lifecycle method ?

My problem: I have unrelated (that is non-sibling, non-descendant or non-common-parent) components which change view based on interactions made on a different component. And, [$on(...)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) does not seem to help my purpose.

And, there arises the need to understand how/why [.$on(..)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on) is made available in the framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$on`-method for implementation of `CommunicationHub` -- common mixin, for non parent <--> child communication (like in your case).

For example: you have two Vue root applications: `RootAppA` and `RootAppB`. To communicate between them, you can create `CommunicationHub` mixin with next code:

```
let CommunicationHub = new Vue();

Vue.mixin({
  data: function () {
    return {
      communicationHub: CommunicationHub
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can send data by emitting custom event from `RootAppA` with `$emit`-method, and get this data by subscribing on this event in `RootAppB`, with method `$on`:

```
let RootAppA = {
  methods: {
    sendData(){
      this.communicationHub.$emit('customEvent', {foo: 'bar', baz: 1, comment: 'custom payload object'});
    }
  }
}

let RootAppB = {
  created(){
    this.communicationHub.$on('customEvent', (payload) => {
      console.log(payload); //{foo: 'bar', baz: 1, comment: 'custom payload object'}
    });
  }
}
```

By the way, please mention that CommunicationHub-pattern is not so flexible solution for bigger apps. So if your application will grow up, perhaps you will want to use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)-library (see my example in [previous so-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47366317/8311719))